# getting select id dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have HTML code like below

```
 <select id="example1">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>

<select id="example2">
    <option id="1">one</option>
    <option id="2">two</option>
    <option id="3">three</option>
    <option id="4">four</option>
</select>
```

and having jquery change call code

```
    $("#example1").on('change', function () {
alert($(this).val());
  });

      $("#example2").on('change', function () {
alert($(this).val());
```

});

instead of passing select id statically, I want to pass it dynamically in jquery. like one on change function to handle both selects. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `class`  to the select element and bind the handler to the class.

```js
$('.selectexample').on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="example1" class="selectexample">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>

<select id="example2" class="selectexample">
  <option id="1">one</option>
  <option id="2">two</option>
  <option id="3">three</option>
  <option id="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Reference to JQuery selectors.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery%20selectors&rlz=1CDGOYI_enGB600GB600&oq=jquery%20selectors&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l2.2902j0j4&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `select` as your selector, which will trigger when either of your `<select>` elements are changed:

```
// When a <select> element is changed
$('select').on('change', function () {
     // Do work
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Or if you needed to be more specific, you could only target elements that have ID attributes that start with "example" using the jQuery ["starts-with" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
$('[id^="example"]').on('change',function(){
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="example1">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>

<select id="example2">
  <option id="1">one</option>
  <option id="2">two</option>
  <option id="3">three</option>
  <option id="4">four</option>
</select>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id') + ' has ' + $(this).val() + ' selected!');
    });
  });
</script>
```